# How can we support all domains in postfix smtp server?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I have installed and configured postfix on our server.

Postfix config file has relay_domain parameter which contains the list of domain names which postfix will support.

Is there a way by which we can support all domain names in postfix without creating relay_domain database list?Edit

Comment: That will be creating an Open relay

Comment: How can we create open relay ? Please give details ..

Comment: with postfix you can't. try sendmail, some older version :)

Comment: We have saas model service hireplug.com for companies social recruitment. We send a lot of emails to them using postfix smtp server. Now every time a recruiter belonging to a company joins , his company domain name has to be added to postfix relay-domain list which is kind of painful . Cron job is one solution which will modify relay-domain list. Is there a better solution, postfix provides out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

explicitly specifying the domains you want to relay mail for is a security measure against spam and other types of misuse of smtp systems.

if you are only interested in automatically enabling relaying for subdomains, you can set parent_domain_matches_subdomains variable.

postfix doesn't support blind relaying ... at least to some extent. in some scenarios, you may use permit_mx_backup to relay for domains that your mail server is listed as a backup (secondary, higher dns mx rr priority) mx. but do carefully read [permit_mx_backup specification](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_mx_backup)  and related documents like [permit_mx_backup_networks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_mx_backup_networks). but this is very dangerous and I already see ways of exploiting it via dns. don't doit.

Comment: We have saas model service hireplug.com for companies social recruitment.                                                       We send a lot of emails to them using postfix smtp server.                                  Now every time a recruiter belonging to a company joins , his company domain name has to be added to postfix relay-domain list which is kind of painful . Cron job is one solution which will modify relay-domain list.                                            Is there a better solution, postfix provides out of the box?

Comment: you don't need to add a domain to relay_domains table to be able to send emails to users from that domain. to do that, configure smtpd_recipient_restrictions to trust email from authed users and trusted networks. for example: smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_non_fqdn_sender

Comment: ... and configure your $my_networks parameter and sasl authentication mechanisms (if needed)

Comment: Configurations main.cf file.                                                              myhostname = srv_name
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = hireplug.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_non_fqdn_sender
relayhost =                                           mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =

Comment: It's sending mail from postfix server using telnet but not forwarding mail when using a email client . Anything missing ?
A quick reply will be appreciated ?

Comment: Getting this error in log while sending email from client:                                      NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from srv1:  <abhay@openweblabs.com>: Relay access denied; from=<abhay@townfi.com> to=<abhay@openweblabs.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>

Comment: Solved! I added client server name in my_networks parameter an it's working fine. Thanks guys for the responses.