# How can we support all domains in postfix smtp server?

Tags: smtp, email, postfix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we support all domains in postfix smtp server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/209532/how-can-we-support-all-domains-in-postfix-smtp-server)

I have installed and configured postfix on our server.

Postfix config file has relay_domain parameter which contains the list of domain names which postfix will support.

Is there a way by which we can support all domain names in postfix without creating relay_domain database list?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can add TLD's in /etc/postfix/relay-domains like this:

.org

.net

.com

.fm

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/24